# winform displaying in classic view outside of ISE

Tags: winforms, powershell

Not sure what is causing this issue but I have a PowerShell script that uses Windows Forms as the UI.  When developing it inside of the PowerShell ISE everything looked nice with modern style buttons.  When I run it from PowerShell it displays in a Windows Classic style view and crashes when I make a call to `New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog`.  Is there a fix for this that I can add to my code so my script not only looks better but actually functions outside of the ISE?

Edit:
This is my function where I call `SaveFileDialog`.  This works inside of the ISE but when I run the script from PowerShell itself it crashes when I call this.

```
function exportToCSV([System.Object[]] $expArray) {
    $save = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $save.CreatePrompt = $False
    $save.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = $True
    $save.DefaultExt = "csv"
    $save.Filter = "CSV (*.csv) | *.csv*"
    $save.Title = "Export to CSV"
    if ($save.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        $expArray | export-csv $save.FileName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the following command in your script before showing the form to get modern style appearance.

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
```

This should however not affect the `savefiledialog`. I'm gonna need more to help you with that since you're saying it works in ISE, but not in normal console.

A workaround for your `SaveFileDialog` is adding:

```
$save.ShowHelp = $true
```

In PS3.0 everything works fine, but in PS2.0 the dialog doesn't show. The `ShowHelp` fixes that, but also gives you an old-style dialog. However, functionality is more imporant then appearance. :)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me!  I have edited my question to include the function I use to call SaveFileDialog.